# tinymce execCommand behaving weird in Chrome

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I got a custom button that when I click it with the editor opened, it does the following:

```
tinymce.execCommand(command, false, action)
```

command is for example "mceToogleFormat", and action can be for example "bold" to toggle a text node from normal to bold.

Weird thing is, if I press that button, it doesn't apply the bold format, and the caret goes to the beginning of the text.
Now if I run the same line of execCommand in the console, it runs perfectly... i'm really intrigued on why this isn't running during runtime with the custom button, but it's working when i write it in the console.

I upgraded the tinymce to the last version 4.1.7.
I was using 4.0.26 and the code works perfectly with it.

After debugging tinymce code and my code, i saw that the range is somehow lost when i click on my custom button.

Is there any way to solve this? Is it a focus problem? I thought about that, but... shouldn't I be losing the focus when i click in the console too? and nevertheless, that works? I can't understand this anymore, I really appreciate any help given.

(Firefox and IE 11 works as intended, only Chrome is having issues)